FFmpeg.AutoGen C# library Can't open Codec G726
I am stuck with FFmpeg.AutoGen G726 Audio codec, it always shows error invalid argument.
Note that I Tried other codecs such as G722, G711 and it is working fine except for G726 codec. I also confirm that my binaries does support G726 codec using this command ffmpeg -formats. Please tell me what could be the reason, and if you know any other library for decoding G726 that would be better
public unsafe class AudioDecoder : IDisposable
 {
   private AVCodecContext* _codecContext;
   private AVCodec* _codec;
   private AVFrame* _frame;
   private AVPacket* _packet;

   public AudioDecoder()
   {
       // Find the G726 decoder
       _codec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_decoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G726);
       if (_codec == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("G726 codec not found.");
       }

       // Allocate codec context
       _codecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(_codec);
       if (_codecContext == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("Failed to allocate codec context.");
       }

       // Print supported sample formats
       Console.WriteLine("Supported sample formats for G726 codec:");
       AVSampleFormat* sample_fmts = _codec->sample_fmts;
       if (sample_fmts != null)
       {
           while (*sample_fmts != AVSampleFormat.AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"Sample format: {*sample_fmts}");
               sample_fmts++;
           }
       }

       // Set codec parameters
       _codecContext->sample_rate = 8000;  // G726 typically uses 8000Hz
       if (_codec->sample_fmts != null)
       {
           _codecContext->sample_fmt = *_codec->sample_fmts;  // Use the first supported sample format
       }
       else
       {
           _codecContext->sample_fmt = AVSampleFormat.AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;  // Fallback to a common format
       }
       _codecContext->bit_rate = 32000;  // Example bitrate for G726

       // Attempt to open the codec with detailed error logging
       int ret = ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(_codecContext, _codec, null);
       if (ret < 0)
       {
           byte[] errBuf = new byte[1024];
           fixed (byte* errPtr = errBuf)
           {
               ffmpeg.av_strerror(ret, errPtr, (ulong)errBuf.Length);
           }
           string errMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(errBuf);
           throw new Exception($"Failed to open codec (Error code: {ret}): {errMessage}");
       }

       // Allocate packet and frame
       _packet = ffmpeg.av_packet_alloc();
       _frame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
       if (_packet == null || _frame == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("Failed to allocate packet or frame.");
       }
   }
}

